# How can I check wether a method is recursive in a test in .Net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've got a simple test suite in .Net core, I would like to test wether a **static** **non-virtual** method is recursive. How could I do that?

This is the class I have:

```cs
using System;

namespace Fibonacci
{
    public class Fibonacci
    {
        public static int GetNumber(int n)
        {
            if (n < 0) throw new ArgumentException("Number mustn't be negative");

            var previousValue = 1;
            var currentValue = 0;

            var result = currentValue;

            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                result += previousValue;
                previousValue = currentValue;
                currentValue = result;
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose is to test if a method of that class, with the exact same signature, but a different implementation, is recursive.

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Recursive calls in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18076673/detect-recursive-calls-in-c-sharp-code)

Comment: The main goal is to have a test suite in order to use in Devskiller. The idea is to have a unit test that fails if the implementation of that method (with the same signature) uses recursion..

Comment: This would be exceedingly difficult to do if you cant use a counter in that method

Comment: C# do not support "tail recursion", so you will be able to test is method recursive or not by calling method with very very big argument, and if method is recursive `StackOverflowException` will be thrown.

Comment: @TheGeneral that's why I'm asking if it's possible, or what workarounds I could use.

Comment: @Fabio I thought of that, but that wouldn't be a reliable way to know if it's recursive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're able to add an attribute the method you want to call, you could use an interceptor pattern.  Check out TinyInterceptor for an example: https://github.com/Jalalx/TinyInterceptor
With it you can get before and after method calls and use a global count to detect any calls > 1.

If you can't add an attribute, you may be able to use reflection.emit to add the attribute dynamically.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit

Hope this helps,
Paul